# Tool to insert text snippets into applications

Tags: scripts, desktop-environments, text-processing, paste

In German you start mails and letters with "Sehr geehrter Herr ....".

I am tired of typing this again and again. And I am tired of configuring applications to give me shortcuts to insert text blocks like this.

Is there a way to insert comment text blocks with the desktop environment?

This way I could insert text blocks in vi, thunderbird, firefox, libreoffice...

Another example: I often need to insert my ssh-pub-key somewhere. I know how to use ssh-copy-id, but again a desktop solution to give me access to a configurable list of text blocks would be great.

Comment: guetti, I noticed I instructed installing `xsel` instead of `xclip`. Updated in the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The script below does the job *with applications that use* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> *to paste text*. It is important to know that it will not work in the `gnome-terminal`* for example.
I tested it on a.o. Firefox, Thunderbird, Libreoffice, Sublime Text and Gedit without any problem.

#### How it works

When the script is called, a window appears, listing snippets you defined. Choose an item (or type its number) and the text fragment will be pasted in the frontmost window of any application that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> "-compatible":

[image]

#### Adding / editing snippets

When you choose `manage snippets`, the script's folder in `~/.config/snippet_paste` opens up in nautilus. To create a new snippet, simply create a text file with your snippet's text. Don't mind the name you give the file; as long as it is plain text, it is ok. The script only uses the file's content and creates a numbered list of all the files ('content) it finds.

[image]

If the snippets directory (`~/.config/snippet_paste`) does not exist, the script creates it for you.

#### How to use

- first install `xdotool` and `xclip`, if it is not installed on your system:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool
  ```

  and

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xclip
  ```
- Copy the script below, save it as `paste_snippets.py`, run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/paste_snippets.py
  ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

home = os.environ["HOME"]
directory = home+"/.config/snippet_paste"
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
# create file list with snippets
files = [
    directory+"/"+item for item in os.listdir(directory) \
         if not item.endswith("~") and not item.startswith(".")
    ]
# create string list
strings = []
for file in files:
    with open(file) as src:
        strings.append(src.read())
# create list to display in option menu
list_items = ["manage snippets"]+[
    (str(i+1)+". "+strings[i].replace("\n", " ").replace\
     ('"', "'")[:20]+"..") for i in range(len(strings))
    ]
# define (zenity) option menu
test= 'zenity --list '+'"'+('" "')\
      .join(list_items)+'"'\
      +' --column="text fragments" --title="Paste snippets"'
# process user input
try:
    choice = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", test]).decode("utf-8")
    if "manage snippets" in choice:
        subprocess.call(["nautilus", directory])
    else:
        i = int(choice[:choice.find(".")])
        # copy the content of corresponding snippet
        copy = "xclip -in -selection c "+"'"+files[i-1]+"'"
        subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", copy])
        # paste into open frontmost file
        paste = "xdotool key Control_L+v"
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", paste])
except Exception:
    pass
```

#### If you are not using nautilus

If you are using another file browser, replace the line (29):

```
subprocess.Popen(["nautilus", directory])
```

by:

```
subprocess.Popen(["<your_filebrowser>", directory])
```

#### Putting the script under a shortcut key combination

For more convenient use, you can create a shortcut to call the script:

- System Settings → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts* → *Custom Shortcuts*
- Click <kbd>+</kbd> to add your command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/paste_snippets.py
  ```

---

The script is also posted on [gist.gisthub](https://gist.github.com/Jacob-Vlijm/cdb543d370c2ea4197cc).

---

### *EDIT

The version below automatically checks if the (`gnome-`) terminal is the frontmost application, and changes the paste command automatically into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Usage and set up is pretty much the same.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

home = os.environ["HOME"]
directory = home+"/.config/snippet_paste"
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
# create file list with snippets
files = [
    directory+"/"+item for item in os.listdir(directory) \
         if not item.endswith("~") and not item.startswith(".")
    ]
# create string list
strings = []
for file in files:
    with open(file) as src:
        strings.append(src.read())
# create list to display in option menu
list_items = ["manage snippets"]+[
    (str(i+1)+". "+strings[i].replace("\n", " ").replace\
     ('"', "'")[:20]+"..") for i in range(len(strings))
    ]
# define (zenity) option menu
test= 'zenity --list '+'"'+('" "')\
      .join(list_items)+'"'\
      +' --column="text fragments" --title="Paste snippets" --height 450 --width 150'

def check_terminal():
    # function to check if terminal is frontmost
    try:
        get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
        get_terms = get(["xdotool", "search", "--class", "gnome-terminal"])
        term = [p for p in get(["xdotool", "search", "--class", "terminal"]).splitlines()]
        front = get(["xdotool", "getwindowfocus"])
        return True if front in term else False
    except:
        return False

# process user input
try:
    choice = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", test]).decode("utf-8")
    if "manage snippets" in choice:
        subprocess.call(["nautilus", directory])
    else:
        i = int(choice[:choice.find(".")])
        # copy the content of corresponding snippet
        copy = "xclip -in -selection c "+"'"+files[i-1]+"'"
        subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", copy])
        # paste into open frontmost file
        paste = "xdotool key Control_L+v" if check_terminal() == False else "xdotool key Control_L+Shift_L+v"
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", paste])
except Exception:
    pass
```

Comment: Hi @guettli, could you give some feedback on the answer? does it work for you, did you run into problems etc?

Comment: Your solution should work, but I still not happy. I wrote down my requirements here https://github.com/guettli/ten-flying-fingers. Current best solution seems to be ibus-typing-booster with a custom word/text list.

Comment: @guettli If requirements are not in the question, you can't expect an answer to meet your requirements :\ I think it is pretty much what you literally asked for. (b.t.w. I am using it myself ever since)

Answer (score 15):

I use **AutoKey** it installs from the Ubuntu Software Center

real easy to use

I have added "phrase"s like my email address `example@gmail.com` by typing `gm` plus hitting tab `<tab>`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice application. Works in the terminal and in gedit. The docs are written by experts ... too many details, no overview :-). But it works - thank you.

Comment: `sudo apt install autokey-gtk` if you're so inclined. And a [very nice tutorial](https://www.maketecheasier.com/autokey-make-your-own-keyboard-shortcuts-in-linux/)