# How to create a custom application launcher that copies a text to my clipboard?

Tags: launcher, clipboard

I want to make a Custom Application Launcher and then add it to my Panel so that every time I click on it, it copy's a pre-loaded line of text, but I don't know how to write the commands for it.

For example, if the pre-loaded line of text is "Hello". I would like it to be so that every time I click on it, it copies the word "Hello" to my clipboard so I can paste it wherever.

Comment: Sounds doable, but how would you (like to) set the text to be pasted? Also, the title says:  *...that copys a text to my clipboard?* but it actually seems you want to *paste* it?

Comment: Furthermore, is this: http://askubuntu.com/a/544388/72216 something you have in mind, or is that to "large".

Comment: @JacobVlijm I do indeed need a text to be copied but if you're talking in perspective of the clipboard then yes, it is being pasted into the clipboard. To put it in pseudo code perspective: Application  is clicked >> system copies the string "Hello" to clipboard.

Comment: ...But is "Hello" the only string you' d need, or should you have to make it "editable?

Comment: @JacobVlijm It should be editable but I have enough coding experience to decipher where in the code I need to edit in order to change the pre-loaded string.

Comment: That seems not the most user-friendly option :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Very nice of you to put thought into it. Is there a specific programming language that the commands for the application launcher takes?

Comment: With a launcher, you can run practically anything/language. The launcher is the easy part. Would you like an example? (python)

Comment: Whay you've described can be simply done with a simple one line script `echo Hello | xclip -sel clip ` . Xclip would need to be installed with apt-get though. Think I could post this as an answer ?

Comment: Of course! @Serg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below an example of an easily customizable setup. It exists of a script, and a `.desktop` file (launcher) to run the script with two options. You can:

- click on the launcher to copy a pre- defined string or line to the clipboard, or:
- right-click on it to set a new string:

  [image]
  [image]

#### How to set up

To be able to copy text to the clipboard, we need to install `xclip`:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Then we need two things:

1. The script:

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import os
   import sys

   wordfile = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.word_file"

   def get_word():
       try:
           copy = "xclip -in -selection c "+"'"+wordfile+"'"
           subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", copy])
       except FileNotFoundError:
           pass

   def set_word():
       try:
           word = "zenity --entry --title='Change the word' --text='Set a new string or line'"
           new_word = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", word]).decode("utf-8").strip()
           open(wordfile, "wt").write(new_word)
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           pass

   arg = sys.argv[1]
   if arg == "-set":
      set_word()
   elif arg == "-get":
       get_word()
   ```

   Copy it into an empty file, save it as `copy_text.py` and *make it executable*(!!)
2. A `.desktop file`, to run the script with two options

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Paste a string
   Exec=/path/to/copy_text.py -get
   Type=Application
   Icon=/path/to/your/icon.png

   Actions=Set a new string;

   [Desktop Action Set a new string]
   Name=Set a new string
   Exec=/path/to/copy_text.py -set
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

   Copy it into an empty file, save it as `paste_text.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`, replace in both the lines, starting with `Exec=`:

   ```
   /path/to/copy_text.py
   ```

   by the actual path to the script, and replace in the line, starting with `Icon=`

   ```
   /path/to/your/icon.png
   ```

   by the actual path to a valid icon (e.g. a `.png` icon of 64x64 px)

Now drag the `.desktop` file to the `Unity` launcher and you'll have your easily customizable setup.

#### Explanation

*Using xclip in a .desktop file*

`xclip` is a utility that can be used to manage the clipboard from the command line. 
To copy a string to the clipboard, you can use the command:

```
echo <string> | xclip -sel clip
```

To copy the content of a *file* to the clipboard:

```
xclip -in -selection c <file>
```

If it would be a *fixed string* that you need, you could indeed, as mentioned by Serg, do with a `.desktop` file with a one- liner:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Paste a string
Exec=/bin/bash -c "echo Hello World | xclip -sel clip"
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
```

or, if you would only have a limited number of (fixed) strings to use:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Paste a string
Exec=/bin/bash -c "echo Monkey | xclip -sel clip"
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/lswitcher/icon/lsw_64.png

Actions=Monkey;eats;banana;

[Desktop Action Monkey]
Name=Copy Monkey
Exec=/bin/bash -c "echo Monkey | xclip -sel clip"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action eats]
Name=Copy eats
Exec=/bin/bash -c "echo eats | xclip -sel clip"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action banana]
Name=Copy banana
Exec=/bin/bash -c "echo banana | xclip -sel clip"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

then create the file, as explained in the answer, and drag it over the `Unity` launcher:

[image]

If the string to copy would be an unpredictable one, it would however mean that you would have to edit the `.desktop` file manually every time you want to change the string, which is not very user- friendly.

*What the script is for*

Therfore, the script creates an external file, `~/.word_file`, with the content of the string you'd like to be copied to the clipboard. The script has two functions:

```py
def get_word():
    try:
        copy = "xclip -in -selection c "+"'"+wordfile+"'"
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", copy])
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

to (try to) read the text to be copied to the clipboard from the file, `pass` if the file doesn't exist.

and:

```py
def set_word():
    try:
        word = "zenity --entry --title='Change the word' --text='Set a new string or line'"
        new_word = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", word]).decode("utf-8").strip()
        open(wordfile, "wt").write(new_word)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
```

to open a `zenity` window in which you can enter the new string or line to write to the file:

[image]

*The `.desktop` file*

finally, calls the two functions of the script with two commands:

```
Exec=/path/to/copy_text.py -get
```

to call the script with the option `-get`, as the "main" command in the `.desktop` file, to be executed with a simple click on the `Unity` launcher's icon, and:

```
Exec=/path/to/copy_text.py -set
```

to call the script with the option `-set`, as a right-click (quicklist)  option.

[image]