# Inserting text with a keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, unicode

I know we can insert some unicode characters by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+[code] combination under Windows, right? I would like to have a similar option under Ubuntu, however in addition to that **I'd need to choose my shortcut keys and text to be inserted**. For example, I want to insert "⭐" character with a combination (it doesn't matter what combination, it may be even <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>123</kbd>).

Is this even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I type ASCII characters like Alt + numpad in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88347/how-can-i-type-ascii-characters-like-alt-numpad-in-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, type an Unicode code point and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the character bound to that Unicode code point;

For example, to insert `⭐`:

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- Type `2b50`
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I suggest you to keep using this method, as most <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+[...], <kbd>Alt</kbd>+[...] and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+[...] sequence will end up conflicting with other functions; however if you really want to use a custom shortcut, you can try your luck and bind a custom shortcut to an `xdotool`command in System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts; for example, the `xdotool` command to insert `⭐` would be:

```
xdotool key --window '$(xdotool getactivewindow)' Ctrl+Shift+U2B50
```

Comment: I would just use compose keys for this. Much cleaner and quite a bit easier. Wait, I'll write an answer for other people who want to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can enable compose keys to create these symbols or even strings of text with ease without remembering these annoying keyboard number-letter combinations.

Open GEdit and insert the following:

```
include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"

<Multi_key>     <1>     <2>     <3> : "Your text"   # Quick description
<Multi_key>     <s>     <t>     <a> : "⭐"  U2B50    # Star Symbol
```

Save this as .XCompose (case sensitive) in your home directory.

Open your keyboard settings (system settings → keyboard settings) and go to the shortcuts tab.
Under the "typing" section you'll find a "Compose Key" setting. Set this to your compose key (I advice right alt)

Gnome
[image: Compose Key setting for gnome]
Unity
[image: Compose Key setting for Unity] 
Xfce
[image: Compose Key setting for xfce. Source: wikipedia Compose Key]

Log out and log back in.
To quickly summon your text press the following keys in sequence <kbd>Compose Key</kbd> → <kbd>1</kbd> → <kbd>2</kbd> → <kbd>3</kbd>.
Just replace 1,2,3,4,5 etc etc with whatever keys you want to use.

[If it isn't working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207025/add-custom-compose-key-sequence-not-working) add

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

to the end of ~/.profile.
If xim isn't working for you you'll have have to install uim (`sudo apt-get install uim`) and replace the xim in ~/.profile with uim and logout and log back in.

Comment: Does this work outside GNOME? Or, mainly, does this work in Unity? if it does, hats off.

Comment: Yes, this works outside of GNOME. In fact, it works as long as you are using the X Window System.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70784/how-can-i-enable-compose-key

Comment: or you can use the terminal with the following command to enable compose keys: `$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['compose:{key}']"`   where `{key}` is your chosen key-name (e.g. `"['compose:ralt']"` would make right alt your compose key.

Answer (score 2):

I have configured AutoKey to insert the `⭐`

> For example, to insert `⭐`:
>
> - Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
> - Type `2b50`
> - Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

to install [**AutoKey**](https://askubuntu.com/a/799654/110556) read:

https://askubuntu.com/a/799654/110556

List of [unicodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Currency_Symbols):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Currency_Symbols
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28glyph%29