# How to use CTRL + ALT + W to print a question mark in a portuguese keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard, shortcuts

**When using Windows**, pressing the combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> prints a `?`character.

When I'm using Ubuntu, this can be done using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, but I'd rather use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

How can I achieve this?

**@EDIT**

I tried setting a custom shortcut, as suggested in an answer, but it doesn't work:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you add to your post the output of `localectl status`, and take a screenshot of the image shown after running this: `gkbd-keyboard-display -l $(localectl status | awk '/X11 Layout/ {print $3}')$'\t'$(localectl status | awk '/X11 Variant/ {print $3}')`? Seems an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Maybe you already have that symbol

Answer (score 1):

The standard for Linux keyboard is <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. But, if your prefer, could customize this shortcut in your keyboard:

1. Go to System Settings > Keyboard, Shortcuts;
2. Create a new Custom Shortcut (chose it and press +);
3. Click on word "Disabled" so it will turn to "New Accelerator...";
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.
5. Close this window

so:[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. Nothing happens when I press CTRL + ALT + W after doing these steps.

Comment: It's funny. I've got a 17.04, and these commands worked for me.

Comment: So I'll suggest you to see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/676422/inserting-text-with-a-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Fellow brazilian here and this was the first thing I searched when I installed Ubuntu. I've been used to using Ctrl + Alt + W for far too long now and simply was unable to readapt to Shift + / hahaha

***I'm going to write this just in case anyone else searches for it in the future.***

Here's how I did it:

---

***Install xdotool***

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

***Creating the script***

(copy and paste or follow along)

```
mkdir scripts
cd scripts
touch ctrl_alt_w.sh
echo 'xdotool keyup ctrl+alt+w
sleep 0.2
xdotool key shift+ctrl+u+0+0+3+f' >> ctrl_alt_w.sh
chmod -R 777 .
```

1. Open the terminal using Ctrl + Alt + T.
2. Create a folder called scripts.
3. Create a script, lets call it ctrl_alt_w for the sake of it.
4. Add my code to the script by using echo.
5. Modify the permission to allow it to run as a program.

Ok! Now the script part is ready. Let's set a shortcut for it:

---

***Creating the shortcut***

6. Go to Settings > Keyboard > Custom Shortcuts
7. Create a new one like so:

> ```
> Name: ?   
> Command: ./scripts/ctrl_alt_w.sh  
> Shortcut: Ctrl + Alt + W
> ```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJCDr.png)

Sources:
[***Creating the script***](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/run-Unix-shell-script-Linux-Ubuntu-command-chmod-777-permission-steps) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299052/how-to-execute-sh-script-from-a-desktop-shortcut); [xdotool docs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html)

Hope it helps someone!