# Is there a way to assign text snippets to keystrokes

Tags: keyboard

I want to create a keystroke that enters ones email address, postal address, city/state, directory name.  How can one create these mappings?

Answer (score 6):

There is no really "obvious" way, i.e., different approaches exist.

**For the current legacy graphical server: Xorg**

Likely the most accessible for newer users is the keyboard macro program [Autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). It offers a graphical user interface to define text snippets and expansions. You can make a shortcut key type certain phrases, but even better, it can watch your typing and when you type an abbreviation you defined (e.g. `:add`) it will expand that into a full phrase.

[Espanso](https://espanso.org/) works in a similar way, but may be harder to learn to setup. You configure it through text files. The documentation is excellent, though.

Many people use custom scripts, that use automation tools like `xdotool` to simulate typing keystrokes, and `xclip` or `xsel` to manipulate the clipboard. Such a script is called using a shortcut key, and then allows to quickly select and insert the snippy. Jacob Vlijm published a ready-to-go script on [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543968/tool-to-insert-text-snippets-into-applications). [Snippy text expander](https://gist.github.com/opennomad/15c4d624dce99066a82d) is a script written in bash. In both examples, you put your text snippets as little text files in a defined folder.

**A very simple approach using only `xdotool` assigned to a shortcut key**

*Single line xdotool commands assigned to a shortcut key*

For very basic needs, you could assign a command that emulates some typing to a shortcut key. For example, if you wish <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to type your full name, then you could assign following command to the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> key.

```
xdotool keyup Shift+F1 type "My full name"
```

*Remark* `keyup` simulates releasing the shortcut key again. If the script kicks in while you are still holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, otherwise, caps would be typed instead.

*Multi-line xdotool scripts*

For more elaborate snippets, you better create a small xdotool script. For example, create a script `address` in a folder, for example in a folder "Snippets" under your home folder. Enter the following text and save.

```
#!/usr/bin/xdotool
keyup Shift+F2
type "My full name"
key Return
type "Street and number"
key Return
type "Zip and City"
```

*Remark*: The shebang line points to the `xdotool` executable. This way, `xdotool` will be loaded to execute the commands that follow. A new line is entered with the "Return" key (<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Make the text file executable using the File Properties dialog in your file manager.

Assign a shortcut key, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to the script: as command, specify the full path name to the script, e.g. `/home/<yourlogin/Snippets/address`.

**For the future graphical server: Wayland**

[Espanso](https://espanso.org/), mentioned above, also supports Wayland.

Command line tools to manipulate the clipboard ([`wl-clipboard`](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard)) and to type characters ([`ydotool`](https://espanso.org/), [`evemu`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Evemu/)) are  available for Wayland. I am not aware of published, ready-to-use snippet scripts thus far.

`wl-clipboard` is available in the Ubuntu software repository. So is `ydotool, but in 22.04, it is a very old version that does not properly work. Fortunatelly, it is rather easy to [compile it on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413829/how-can-i-install-and-use-the-latest-ydotool-keyboard-automation-tool-working-o).