# Custom shortcuts for pasting multiline text Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I used to use Autohotkey to do this on Windows; I'm wondering if there is a parallel way that I can do this in Ubuntu. I typeset a lot of math using LaTeX which can get pretty tedious and Autohotkey was a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Espanso](https://espanso.org/install/) is very new but excellent tool, cross platform and, in addition to Xorg, it now also supports Wayland, the new display manager that is now default in Ubuntu 22.04.

All other tools only work on Xorg, and thus on a default install of Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 which use Xorg by default.

- The tool Autokey is available in the Ubuntu Software center.

Scripts can be used as well. Assign these to a shortcut key. Text fragments are stored in separate text files with the names of the abbreviations you want to use. You type the abbreviation, hit the shortcut key you assigned to the script, and the script will automatically cut the abbreviation to the clipboard, then replace the clipboard content with the full text, and paste it back.

- [Snippy](https://github.com/christopherowenowens/snippy) is a simple bash script.
- Jacob Vlijm presented a [python script](https://askubuntu.com/a/544388/558158) on this site that allows to select snippets from a dialog.